# Simple Press Wordpress plugin problems

Tags: wordpress

I needed a wordpress plugin for forums, so i installed Simple-Press plugin, the plugin works perfect with good controls and every thing seems perfect, but one problem i am having is on the Profile page of each user, i am getting this error

http://prntscr.com/7auib (screenshot)
Profile form could not be found [//wp-content/plugins/simple-press/forum/profile/forms/sp-form-global-options.php]

Can any one help out on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother with this plugin. Use bbPress which is the best and most compatible forum plugin for WordPress. It's made by the WordPress team.